# Moving a plot label along with a moving threshold line

Tags: plotting, manipulate

Here is a simple `Manipulate` expression with a threshold.

```
Manipulate[
  Show[
    Plot[
      Piecewise[{{ξ x^2, x <= 1/(2 ξ - 1)}, {x, x > 1/(2 ξ - 1)}}], {x, 0, 5}], 
    Graphics[Line[{{1/(2 ξ - 1), 0}, {1/(2 ξ - 1), 25}}]]], 
  {ξ, 0, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

How to label the foot of the threshold line in such a way that it moves with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to add a text element in the graphics object:

```
Manipulate[
 Show[Plot[
   Piecewise[{{ξ x^2, x <= 1/(2 ξ - 1)}, {x, 
      x > 1/(2 ξ - 1)}}], {x, 0, 5}], 
  Graphics[{Line[{{1/(2 ξ - 1), 0}, {1/(2 ξ - 1), 25}}], 
    Text["label", {1/(2 ξ - 1), 0}]}]], {ξ, 0, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I differ from xslittlegrass on what you want the label to be. I would modify your code like so:

```
Manipulate[
  With[{threshold = 1/(2 ξ - 1)},
    Show[
      Plot[
        Piecewise[{{ξ x^2, x <= threshold}, {x, x > threshold}}], {x, 0, 5}],
      Graphics[
        {HalfLine[{threshold, 0}, {0, 1}],
         Text[Round[threshold, .01], {threshold, -2.25}]}],
      PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {0, 16}},
      PlotRangePadding -> {{Automatic, .1}, {3., Automatic}},
      PlotRangeClipping -> False]],
 {{ξ, .6}, 0.55, 1., Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image: demo]

This produces a moving label that gives the current value of `threshold`.

Answer (score 2):

```
Manipulate[Plot[Piecewise[{{ξ x^2, x <= 1/(2 ξ - 1)}, {x, x > 1/(2 ξ - 1)}}], {x, 0, 5}, 
        GridLines -> {{{1/(2 ξ - 1), Directive[Thick, Red]}}, {}}, 
        Epilog -> Text[Framed[ToString@Round[1/(2 ξ - 1), .1], 
                              Background -> Orange], {1/(2 ξ - 1), -.5}], 
        PlotRangePadding -> .9], 
  {{ξ, .7}, .0, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]